# How to Config CSF for skinsrestorer on server Minecraft

Tags: java, firewall, minecraft

I'm having a minecraft server, running on centos 7. Do my servers were attacked repeatedly, so I want to install a firewall to minimize the attacks. I use a firewall CSF. I've configured everything, but could not make the plugin work Skinsrestorer. My server uses bungee Cord.

Firewall CSF: http://www.configserver.com/cp/csf.html
Plugin Skinsrestorer: https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/skinsrestorer.2124/

I run debug:

```
skinsrestorer.shared.utils.MojangAPI$SkinRequestException
at skinsrestorer.shared.utils.MojangAPI.getUUID(MojangAPI.java:34)
at skinsrestorer.bungee.commands.AdminCommands$2.run(AdminCommands.java:215)
at net.md_5.bungee.scheduler.BungeeTask.run(BungeeTask.java:63)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thank!

Comment: Can you give example of error?

Comment: I added ip 52.85.151.12(https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/) allow all for csf but it is not work :(